# jQuery .find not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="t">
    <input type="button" class="theClass" />
    <input type="button" class="theClass" />
    <input type="button" class="notTheClass" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var result = $('#t > input').find('.theClass').length;
console.log(result);
```

---

Expected result: `2`

Actual result: `0`

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RNXzg/).

---

from [jQuery specs on .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector

Can someone explain me why `.find()` is filtering out all the elements instead of just returning the 2 I'm searching for?

Side note:
`$('#t > input').length` returns, correctly: `3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using find ? when you can do this.

```
var result = $('#t > input.theClass').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#t > input").filter(".theClass")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MTt4u/

Answer (score 3):

You're looking within the inputs, which is wrong, because you won't find anything. Do this way:

```
var result = $('#t').find('input.theClass').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are looking for `'.theClass'` as a child of the `input`. You need to do:

```
var result = $('#t input.theClass').length;
```

or

```
var result = $('#t').find('input.theClass').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with

```
var result = $('#t > .theClass').length;
```

There is no reason to use `find()`.